# SharePoint 2013 перенос, синхронизация данных между тестом и продуктивом

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Есть тестовая среда(разработка) SharePoint 2013 и продуктивная среда. Если возможность быстрого копирования сайта с одного сервера на другой. SPmeta2 хорошо, но нужно описывать модель вручную поля списков сами списки, много js кода, html форм, итд итп. Можно упростить этот момент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал консольное приложение через CSOM получаю данные клиентским кодом название списков, поля, контент типы, internal name итд (можно конечно и через SSOM). Через создание кода С# используя текстовые шаблоны Т-4 получаем модель SPMETA2. Данные выгружаю используя linq to sharepoint каждый список в каждый файл и обратная загрузка.